# Dividing n numbers into two groups each having sum less than equals k

Tags: algorithm

There are n numbers, ranging 1-100. n ranges in 1-1000.

Another number k. Its bounds are 1 <= k <= 10^6

How to check if its possible to divide the given n numbers in two sets such that the sum of both group numbers is <=k.

I am looking for a high level implementation approach or an algorithm which will return true if the division is possible.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - updated the question. - "high level implementation approach or an algorithm which will return true if the division is possible."

Comment: And you tried? Don't you think this is a bit broad? You checked out the partition-problem and np-hardness?

Comment: I tried a DP based approach and one based on a sorting. Both didn't work out. Posting it here after being stuck with this for more than 5 hrs

Comment: Without presenting your approaches and describing what ```did not work out``` means, this is too broad.

Comment: @G.D . . . Yes, such an algorithm exists.  It is called brute-force -- try all possible combinations.  That answers your question.

Comment: @sascha - Not sure how it will help as its incorrect solution, this was my last tried approach in java -https://www.pastiebin.com/59bd2afb18860

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I didn't try brute, but i am sure that will time out.

Comment: Are you aware of the implications np-hardness gives in regards to brute-force (ignoring pseudo-polynomial approaches for now)? This might be irrelevant to your task as it seems it's some competition-like task (*will time out*, but this also means that's is questionable if you should ask here and i'm pretty sure a good web-search will help then.

Answer (score 0):

A DP based solution with a complexity of O(n*sum)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += a[i];
  }

  int[][] dp = new int[n + 1][sum + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    dp[i][0] = 1;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= sum; j++) {
      dp[i + 1][j] = dp[i][j];
      if (a[i] <= j) {
        dp[i + 1][j] |= dp[i][j - a[i]];
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = sum / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (dp[n][i] == 1) {
      int x = sum - i;
      if (x > k || i > k) {
        System.out.println("NO");
      } else {
        System.out.println("YES");
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```